# ScrollTop js - Firefox doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, scrolltop

I have a problem with my scrollTop javascript code only for firefox. I have put some anchors on href links, and only on chrome/explorer does working the smooth scroll. On firefox doesn't. It jumps only on that button but it doesn't scroll to it.

Firefox console error: This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!

My code:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
    $scrollWrapper = $(document);

    scroll = function scroll(value, hash) {
        $scrollWrapper.scrollTop(value);
        currentHash = hash;
    };
} else {
    $scrollWrapper = $('html, body');

    scroll = function scroll(value, hash) {
        $(document).off('scroll.currentHash');

        $scrollWrapper.animate({
            scrollTop: value + 30
        }, {
            delay: 500,
            complete: function () {
                currentHash = hash;
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Try: `$scrollWrapper = $(window);`

Comment: "Firefox scrollTop stackoverflow" returns quite a few results. Did you take a look at these?

Comment: Yes, but without success.. :( I forgot to say what is not working.. It jumps only on that button but it doesn't scroll to it..

Comment: @Guedes Yes i did.. and nothing :(